# Using NodeJs Environment Variables in ViteJS React files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite

I use ViteJs to generate an ReactJs Project. In the vite.config.ts file we can see following:

```
const isDev = process.env["DFX_NETWORK"] !== "ic"
const network = process.env.DFX_NETWORK ||
   (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "ic" : "local");
```

VueJs use `import.meta.env` ([documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript)) in Javascript files to consume environmment variable.
But for my use case i need to also use the nodejs `process.env` in my javascript/typescript files.

How can i setup ViteJs so that `process.env` can also be use?

Answer (score 0):

`VITE_*` environment variables are automatically exposed to the built application as you described, in `import.meta.env` once the built code is running.

It's possible to use the vite build configs [`define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) property to replace specific strings in the build output. An environment variable can be opted into this process via:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')

  return {
    define: {
      'process.env': {
        'DFX_NETWORK': env.DFX_NETWORK,
        'NODE_ENV':  env.NODE_ENV,
      }
    },
  })
}
```

It's extremely unlikely you want to expose all of `process.env` to the built app in this manner as that will likely include private information from the build system.